Sublime Text: How can I run a command across all the tabs open in a window?
I'm using sublime to code. We get html files from third parties and the first thing I do is run a command. So far I've been manually running the command on the 12+ tabs individually.
I've tried googling with no luck.
I just want to run that command on all the open tabs. How can I do this?

What kind of command are you trying to run?
